# "Show source" no longer displays the TeX-source on the main site (FF 5, OS X 10.6)

Tags: support, bug, status-norepro

The following happens to me using Firefox 5.0 on OS X 10.6.7, but also on Firefox 4.0.3 (with all plugins disabled and emptied cache, restarted etc). It doesn't happen with Safari 5.0.5, though.

---

Until recently, right-clicking on a formula and selecting "show source" yielded a pop-up window showing the LaTeX-source. For instance, the very simple formula

$$\max{\{a,b\}} = \frac{a+b}{2} + \frac{|a-b|}{2}$$

appearing in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46939/maximum-and-minimum/46940#46940) was created using

```
\max{\{a,b\}} = \frac{a+b}{2} + \frac{|a-b|}{2}
```

Right-clicking on the formula (on the main site!) and selecting "show source" now yields the following human-unreadable garbage (excerpt of about a screen full of similar lines)

```
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" display="block">
  <mo movablelimits="true">max</mo>
  <mrow>
    <mo fence="false" stretchy="false">{</mo>
    <mi>a</mi>
    <mo>,</mo>
    <mi>b</mi>
    <mo fence="false" stretchy="false">}</mo>
  </mrow>
...
```

On the meta site, we still have the desired result. Could this please be re-installed on the main site, because this feature is very useful for referring LaTeX-unsavvy users to, while the new result is of no use, really.

Comment: I don't see any problems - I get the right popup when I click "show source" (on the main site!).

Comment: Works fine for me (Win7, Chrome 13)

Comment: By the way: if it matters, I currently use FF 5 on OS X 10.6.7, but I don't think this is browser and OS specific.

Comment: @Theo: It might play a role that FF 5 is not officially released and hence not a supported browser for the site.

Comment: @Hendrik: I don't know what it means for FF 5 to be "officially released". My FF 4 updated itself to 5 and when I go to mozilla.org, they automatically provide me with FF 5 when I'm trying to download the software.

Comment: I just downloaded FF 5, and it works fine for me.

Comment: @Theo: I'm really sorry, I'm not up to date. I only knew that FF 4 was released not too long ago, and this was _years_ after FF 3. It came as a complete surprise to me that FF 5 has been released already!

Comment: Thanks @Jonas. I tried several things, but it still doesn't work as I think it should with FF 5. On the other hand, this feature isn't really important for me, and if no-one else experiences this problem, I don't care much. What is the proper procedure? Should I leave that question or should I delete it?

Comment: @Theo Why, leave it, maybe someone else has the same problem

Comment: @Hendrik: I was surprised, too. IIRC FF4 was released in March and FF5 a few days ago, maybe they just increased the wrong counter as I don't experience much difference :) and the update was described as "stability fixes".

Comment: I would leave it.  If someone figures out what's causing it, it might help other users.  At worst, it can be tagged [status-norepro] and forgotten.

Comment: Okay, very well then. I leave it.

Comment: @Hendrik and Theo: Mozilla decided to change their versioning model after Firefox 4. This is supposed to "induce quicker turn-around in implementing features" (paraphrasing the official statement), but I think it is just copy-catting the rapid Major version number bumps of Google Chrome. See [here](https://wiki.mozilla.org/RapidRelease).

Comment: @Theo: The menu in FF5 on OSX 10.6.7 works fine for me.  Make sure to use "Show Source" not "View Selection Source".

Comment: @Jack: Thanks a lot for that, so it must be something on my machine, I'll try to figure out what exactly myself. What you're suggesting is not the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't reproduce, in Firefox 5 on Windows 7:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for looking into it.